# ES6 Check property value in deep nested dynamic object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

My data set:

```
{
    courseID003: {
        studentID34: {
            assigned: false
            dueDate: null
        }
        studentID34: {
            assigned: false
            dueDate: null
        }
    }
    courseID007: {
        studentID89: {
            assigned: true
            dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
        }
        studentID111: {
            assigned: true
            dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
        }
        studentID115: {
            assigned: false
            dueDate: null
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

I have a number of course objects that contain student objects. Each course could contain a different number of students.

I need to search every course and every student to see if the assigned property is set to true.

Ideally, I'd like to call a function that performs this search and simply returns true or false. When searching, as soon as an assigned property is found set to true, the search would exit and return true. If all assigned properties are set to false for every student in every course, then return false.

I hope this question makes sense and I hope the data set makes sense/properly formatted ( I am dealing with all objects -- no arrays). All the course objects are in an object.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please add the question...? what does not work?

Comment: Looks like you need two nested loops. Have you tried to write them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are!

```js
const data = {
    courseID003: {
        studentID34: {
            assigned: false,
            dueDate: null
        },
        studentID34: {
            assigned: false,
            dueDate: null
        }
    },
    courseID007: {
        studentID89: {
            assigned: true,
            dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
        },
        studentID111: {
            assigned: true,
            dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
        },
        studentID115: {
            assigned: false,
            dueDate: null
        }
    }
}

const search = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data).some(courseKey => {
    return Object.keys(data[courseKey]).some(studentKey => {
      return data[courseKey][studentKey]['assigned']
    })
  })
}

console.log(search(data))
```

Reference: [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a bad time searching through that data as written.  The real issue is your choice of data structure.  In two places, you are using an object when you should be using an array.

Here is the same data but with `courses` encoded as an array, which is traversable with the [rich set of array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).  I've made the same change to the collection of students for each course.

```js
let courses = [
    {
        id: 'courseID003',
        students: [
            {
                id: 'studentID34',
                assigned: false,
                dueDate: null
            },
            {
                id: 'studentID34',
                assigned: false,
                dueDate: null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 'courseID007',
        students: [
            {
                id: 'studentID89',
                assigned: true,
                dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
            },
            {
                id: 'studentID111',
                assigned: true,
                dueDate: "2018-12-07 15:51"
            },
            {
                id: 'studentID115',
                assigned: false,
                dueDate: null
            }
        ]
    }
];

let unassignedStudents = Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  [],
  courses.map(c => c.students.filter(s => !s.assigned)));

console.log('unassignedStudents:',unassignedStudents);
```

With this improved data structure, you can find all 'unassigned' students like this:

```
let unassignedStudents = Array.prototype.concat.apply(
  [],
  courses.map(c => c.students.filter(s => !s.assigned)));
```

Hopefully you can see how this change in structure opens new doors for you.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, keep in mind Object.values might require a polyfill (for IE) as well as flatMap (missing in many browsers atm).

```
const courses = Object.values(data);
const students = courses.flatMap(course => Object.values(course);
const result = students.some(student => student.assigned);
```

Comment: Does not really need `flatMap`. `map` would suffice.

Comment: @DavidSherman, I tried implementing this but kept getting a type error on `student.assigned`: `Property 'assigned' does not exist on type 'any[]'.` I tried creating an interface for this and still could not get this working. I accepted another answer as it worked perfect for this situation.